# Custom hyperlink for image displayed through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, dropdown

I have a simple html page with which displays the image as per the selection from a dropdown menu.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div id="mymenu">
<select id="men" onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);chngSel()">
<option value="product_a.png" selected>Product A</option>
<option value="product_b.png" selected>Product B</option>
<option value="product_c.png" selected>Product C</option>
</select>
</div>
<img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="all_products.png">
</head>
</html>
```

The image is displayed as per the selected option.

When Product B option is selected, the product_b.png displays, is it possible to change the hyperlink to product_b.html page once the product_b.png is clicked? A variable href for displayed image?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML

```
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="mymenu">
       <select id="men">
            <option data-url="/productA" value="product_a.png">Product A</option>
            <option data-url="/productB" value="product_b.png">Product B</option>
            <option data-url="/productC" value="product_c.png">Product C</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="all_products.png">
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var $imageToSwap = $('#imageToSwap');

    // change the source of the image
    $('#men').on('change', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            src = $this.val(),
            url = $this.data('url');

        $imageToSwap.attr({ src }).data({ url });
    });

    // click event for the image
    $imageToSwap.on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            url = $this.data('url');

        location.href = url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but you can't have 3 Selected options at once.
Selected is used as a "default selection". Try using it only once.